# Insert retrofit array data into sqlite

Tags: android, json, sqlite, retrofit2

I have manage to retrieve data from the server using retrofit, after that i would like to insert it into sqlite database, however there's some error. what am i doing that is wrong? because i set it into the textview and it shows on the output. why is it return as null object?

[image: Error that i receive]

My retrofit part of code

```
    private void loadJSON() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String getpaspot = intent.getStringExtra("pasport");

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON(getpaspot);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                jemaah = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getJemaah()));
                adapter = new JemaahAdapter(jemaah);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                //List<Jemaah> jemaahs = jsonResponse.getJemaah();
                for (Jemaah j : jemaah){
                    if (j.getManifest1_no_paspot().equals(getpaspot)){
                        reqjemaah = j;

                        String namaJ = reqjemaah.getManifest1_nama().trim();
                        String paspotJ = reqjemaah.getManifest1_no_paspot().trim();
                        String akaunJ = reqjemaah.getManifest1_no_akaun().trim();

                        textView1.setText(namaJ);
                        textView2.setText(paspotJ);
                        textView3.setText(akaunJ);

                        myDb.saveUser(akaunJ, paspotJ, namaJ);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

SQLiteHandler

```
    public void saveUser(String manifest1_no_akaun, String manifest1_no_paspot, String manifest1_nama) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NOAKAUN, manifest1_no_akaun );
    values.put(KEY_NOPASPOT, manifest1_no_paspot );
    values.put(KEY_NAMA, manifest1_nama );

    db.insert(TABLE_USER,null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Looks like myDb is null.

Comment: @LeoPelozo, yea why is it null? is it because i retrieve it using the model getter?

Comment: You need to initialize it somewhere. How's saveUser class called? You need to instanciate it.

Comment: @LeoPelozo oh i see, thanks, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare & initialise `SQLiteHandler` class object before using it.

Something like,

```
SQLiteHandler myDb = new SQLiteHandler(); //add this line
myDb.saveUser(akaunJ, paspotJ, namaJ);
```

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Use **Realm** for storing the data in the database. **It can store object of class without declaring its database structure.** It is more convenient.